# Adding Users to Groups in Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to moodle. I am not knowing how to assign users into groups.

I am not getting the users list when I want to assign the users into groups in my test site.

I started a course and put the mode in Force Groups mode.

I enrolled some test users into the course and then I got these users to add in the Groups I've created.

But, in order to access the course, the user should be asked for the enrolment key of the group. But the user is accessible to the course even without the key.

Should I need to review my permissions?

Comment: I think this question belongs to Moodle forums at moodle.org

Comment: Yes, I posted there, but I didn't get any reply there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle is not asking for enrolment key while enrolling into the course because you are doing it in a wrong way.

To use auto assign group enrolment key feature you need to follow following thing  -

1. Add self enrollment plugin in course with **Enrolment key = anything** and **Use group enrolment keys = YES**
2. Create a group with enrolment key.
3. Now login as student go to that course you will see enrolment key option type enrolment key which you have mention while creating a group.
4. That particular user will automatically assigned to that group.